# ¿Cómo evitar imprimir ciertos DIV en HTML?

Tags: html, css

Necesito imprimir una página **HTML** donde hago cotizaciones, pero me salen los botones de acciones en la parte de abajo y necesito evitar esto.

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo que tienes para comprender mejor tu pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

### Ocultar elementos durante la impresión

Debes utilizar las ***Media Queries*** para evitar imprimir botones. Es decir, podrías hacer algo parecido a esto:

```css
/* Cuando el dispositivo de salida sea una impresora */
@media print {

  /* Se aplicará la siguiente regla CSS */
  button,
  [type="button"],
  [type="submit"],
  [type="reset"] {
    display: none;
  }

}
```

O definir una clase denominada `.ocultar-al-imprimir` para establecerla en los elementos que no desees mostrar durante la impresión.

**Por ejemplo:**

```css
/* Cuando el dispositivo de salida sea una impresora */
@media print {

  /* Utilizar una regla parecida a ésta: */
  .ocultar-al-imprimir {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Explicado lo anterior veamos la siguiente **Demo:**

```js
imprimir.onclick = () => {
  print();
}
```

```css
@media print {
  .ocultar-al-imprimir {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>Cotización</h1>
  <p class="ocultar-al-imprimir">Intrucciones: Haz click en imprimir para imprimir</p>
  <button class="ocultar-al-imprimir" id="imprimir">Imprimir</button>
  <button class="ocultar-al-imprimir">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A vuelo de pájaro lo que se entiende es que necesitas imprimir en físico un formulario de HTML y en esta aparecen botones de acción del formulario que no quieres que se impriman, entonces lo que puedes hacer es hacer click derecho con el ratón encima de los botones, y luego haces click en "Inspeccionar  elemento", requieres algún conocimiento básico de HTML para que en la consola del navegador selecciones el elemento y luego en la columna de propiedades de estilo le agregues una regla tipo "display: none;", y así se remueve de la pantalla y no te saldrá impreso.

Comment: Entendido, para en otra entonces